# Input range connected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't figure out how I can connect two input range.

```js
$('#SF_range').on('input', function() {
    console.log('SDBX = ' + this.value + ' | Seafile = ' + $('#SDBX_range').val());
    var add = (this.max - this.value) + $('#SDBX_range').val();
    $('#SDBX_range').val(add);
    console.log('SDBX = ' + this.value + ' | Seafile = ' + $('#SDBX_range').val()); 
});
$('#SDBX_range').on('input', function() {
    var add = (this.max - this.value) + $('#SF_range').val();
    $('#SF_range').val(add);
    console.log('SDBX = ' + this.value + ' | Seafile = ' + $('#SF_range').val());
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
SDBX
<input type="range" min="0" max="400" value="400" class="mdl-slider mdl-js-slider" id="SDBX_range">
                                    
Coffre
<input type="range" min="0" max="400" value="100" class="mdl-slider mdl-js-slider" id="SF_range">
```

The goal is to transmit the value of one input to another.

[image]

Comment: So when one changes, the other gets the same value? Or that when you adjust one the value of the other equals max-value?

Comment: By 'transmit' I assume you mean that the total of both sliders should be `400`...?

Comment: I mean if I remove 50 from input1 I add 50 to input2

Comment: What is hard with it? Max - Value of Other  = new value

Comment: @epascarello like (this.max - this.value) + value_of_other ?

Comment: no.... you should not care about the value of the other one. other.value = this.max - this.value

Comment: Why ? If I want to add/remove some value ?

Comment: Did you TRY IT?

Comment: Wanted to understand

Comment: Not sure what is hard to understand. basic math: `one.value + two.value = max.value` so 'two.value = max.value - one.value` and 'one.value = max.value - two.value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understood correctly your issue...

```js
var $sf = $('#SF_range');
var $sdbx = $('#SDBX_range');

$sf.on('input', function() {
  $sdbx.val(this.max - this.value);
  console.log('SDBX =', $sdbx.val(), ' | Seafile = ', $sf.val());
});
$sdbx.on('input', function() {
  $sf.val(this.max - this.value);
  console.log('SDBX =', $sdbx.val(), ' | Seafile = ', $sf.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
SDBX
<input type="range" min="0" max="400" value="400" class="mdl-slider mdl-js-slider" id="SDBX_range">
                                    
Coffre
<input type="range" min="0" max="400" value="100" class="mdl-slider mdl-js-slider" id="SF_range">
```